# How do I pack an INT32 into my MessagePack using Java?

Tags: java, msgpack

I'm having an issue where I need to send an INT32 to another application, but from what I've read, *messagepack.putInt* and *messagepack.putLong* will try to optimize this into UINT32 which is causing problems for the receiving application.

The receiving application is giving me the error message

```
decode error, skipping message. msgp: attempted to decode type "uint" with method for "int"
```

I am using maven with the dependency

```
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.msgpack</groupId>
   <artifactId>msgpack-core</artifactId>
   <version>0.8.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Someone else had this same issue and stated the solution to it was as follows

"*OK, so we found the problem, it seems like metricTank requires the time property of the message object to be serialized as INT32, however the packInt (or packLong) will always try to optimize it into UINT32 which metricTank doesnt like. so we had to use addPayload and serialize MessagePacker.Code.INT32, and then the actual 4 bytes of the time property.*"

But I am unsure what to do and I am unable to contact the OP.

I have tried the following but it does not work

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1 + Long.BYTES);
buf.put(MessagePack.Code.INT32);
buf.putLong(md.time);
packer.addPayload(buf.array());
```

The bytes array needs to be 5 in length, first byte is the header, being **0xd2** and the other 4 bytes need to be the value

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
            dos.writeLong(md.time);
            dos.close();
            byte[] longBytes = baos.toByteArray();

            ByteBuffer lBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    lBytes.put(longBytes[i]);
            }

            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(5);
            buf.put((byte) 0xd2);
            buf.put(lBytes.array());
```

This produces no error, but the time value is incorrect when received.

Could someone show me how I can pack an INT32 into my MessagePack rather than UINT32 or show me how I can pack the data in the correct way so it is unpacked correctly on the receiving application?

---

The receiving application is written in [Go](https://golang.org/) and uses the [tinylib msgp](https://github.com/tinylib/msgp) library to decode the data

```
// ReadInt64Bytes tries to read an int64
// from 'b' and return the value and the remaining bytes.
// Possible errors:
// - ErrShortBytes (too few bytes)
// - TypeError (not a int)
func ReadInt64Bytes(b []byte) (i int64, o []byte, err error) {
    l := len(b)
    if l < 1 {
        return 0, nil, ErrShortBytes
    }

    lead := b[0]
    if isfixint(lead) {
        i = int64(rfixint(lead))
        o = b[1:]
        return
    }
    if isnfixint(lead) {
        i = int64(rnfixint(lead))
        o = b[1:]
        return
    }

    switch lead {
    case mint8:
        if l < 2 {
            err = ErrShortBytes
            return
        }
        i = int64(getMint8(b))
        o = b[2:]
        return

    case mint16:
        if l < 3 {
            err = ErrShortBytes
            return
        }
        i = int64(getMint16(b))
        o = b[3:]
        return

    case mint32:
        if l < 5 {
            err = ErrShortBytes
            return
        }
        i = int64(getMint32(b))
        o = b[5:]
        return

    case mint64:
        if l < 9 {
            err = ErrShortBytes
            return
        }
        i = getMint64(b)
        o = b[9:]
        return

    default:
        err = badPrefix(IntType, lead)
        return
    }
}
```

This checks the first byte, and if the first byte is equal to **mint32** which is **0xd2**, then the next four bytes are read, which is the value of the long using **getmint32**

```
func getMint32(b []byte) int32 {
    return (int32(b[1]) << 24) | (int32(b[2]) << 16) | (int32(b[3]) << 8) | (int32(b[4]))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular issue, the receiving application had to receive an INT32 and the bytes array needs to be 5 in length. The first byte is the header **0xd2** as seen in the OP. This tells the decoding method that it's an INT32. The next four 4 bytes is the time value.

I was forgetting that a long is 8 bytes so we just need to use epoch time which is an integer.

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
        dos.writeInt((int)(md.time/1000));
        dos.close();
        byte[] timeBytes = baos.toByteArray();


        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(5);
        buf.put((byte) 0xd2);//header
        buf.put(timeBytes);//time value (int32 bytes not uint32)
```